# Manually adjusting parameters of a torch.nn.Module

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I had a simple neural network defined by:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2,2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2,2)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x
    
net = Net()
```

Doing the following:

```
for param in net.parameters():
    print(param.data)
```

results in something like:

```
tensor([[-0.0776,  0.2409],
        [ 0.3478, -0.6820]])
tensor([-0.6311,  0.2323])
tensor([[-0.5466,  0.0341],
        [ 0.5822,  0.7005]])
tensor([-0.5624,  0.3278])
```

Let's say that I have a tensor([[0,0],[0,1]]) and I wanted to replace the first
param.data with my custom tensor.

Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible, even though I dont know a reason why you would want to do this haha, anyways, this should be it:

```py
replace_with = tensor([[0,0],[0,1]])

for parameter in net.parameters():
    parameter.data = replace_with
    break
```

Now the first element of the parameters should be your custom tensor. I hope that solves your issue :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure why I overlooked this simple solution.